# ¿Se puede comprobar si un fichero está abierto?

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo, stream

Me gustaría saber si hay forma de determinar si un fichero está abierto o en uso en la máquina del usuario. Necesitaría alguna función tipo "File.isOpen()". ¿Sería posible de determinar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/check-if-file-is-already-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes saber si un archivo está abierto por otro proceso en Java puro.

Pero puedes llamar un utilitario del sistema operativo como `lsof | grep miarchivo` en MacOs. En el caso de Windows tendrías que hacer un llamado nativo del sistema operativo o llamar un utilitario especial como `ProcessMon`.

**Replantea la pregunta**

Pero si puedes chequear si el archivo es leíble o escribible según las reglas del sistema operativo.

Sin embargo, también puede ser que uno revisa si el archivo está bloqueado por otro proceso, sale falso, pero luego al querer abrir o escribir falla de nuevo.

**Entonces, cuál es la solución?**

Lo más simple es intentar abrirlo para lectura y/o escritura, y si funciona funciona. Si lanza una Excepción entonces ya tienes tu respuesta.

Esta es una ocasión donde las excepciones te favorecen y se encargan de problemas como condiciones carreras y concurrencia que suceden al usar un recurso compartido.

**Resumen:** inténtalo! Si funciona está disponible. Sino no lo está.

**Ojo:** dependiendo del sistema operativo y el tipo de archivo no necesariamente es exclusivo el bloqueo del archivo. Entonces es importante bloquearlo para escritura. Este artículo muestra cómo se puede hacer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible